# JDBC ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to make a simple java program and trying to implement JDBC over it.
But I am getting an exception ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Here is the logcat:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at vehicles.Vehicles.main(Vehicles.java:43)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is my java code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package vehicles;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Akshay Sood
 */
public class Vehicles extends JFrame{
public static JLabel manfName,cost,modelNo,year,color;

public static JTextField colorTXT,costTXT,yearTXT,modelNoTXT,manfNameTXT;

public static JButton submit,reset;

static String Manufacturer,ModelNo,Year,Color,Cost;

static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/VEHICLE";
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "8851";
static ResultSet resultSet;
static Statement statement = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        statement = conn.createStatement();

        init();
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setTitle("Vehicle Registration");
        jFrame.setSize(800, 1600);
        jFrame.setLayout(null);
        jFrame.show();
        jFrame.add(manfName);
        jFrame.add(modelNo);
        jFrame.add(year);
        jFrame.add(color);
        jFrame.add(cost);
        jFrame.add(manfNameTXT);
        jFrame.add(modelNoTXT);
        jFrame.add(yearTXT);
        jFrame.add(colorTXT);
        jFrame.add(costTXT);
        jFrame.add(submit);
        jFrame.add(reset);

    }

    private static void init() {
       manfName  = new JLabel();
        manfName.setText("Manufacturer: ");
        manfName.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 10);


        modelNo = new JLabel();
        year = new JLabel();
        color = new JLabel();
        cost = new JLabel();

        modelNo.setText("Model No :");
        year.setText("Year of Purchase:");
        color.setText("Color:");
        cost.setText("Cost:");

        modelNo.setBounds(10, 40, 150, 10);
        year.setBounds(10, 70, 150, 10);
        color.setBounds(10, 100, 150, 10);
        cost.setBounds(10, 130, 150, 10);

        manfNameTXT = new JTextField();
        modelNoTXT = new JTextField();
        yearTXT = new JTextField();
        colorTXT = new JTextField();
        costTXT = new JTextField();

        manfNameTXT.setBounds(300, 10, 150, 20);
        modelNoTXT.setBounds(300, 40, 150, 20);
        yearTXT.setBounds(300, 70, 150, 20);
        colorTXT.setBounds(300, 100, 150, 20);
        costTXT.setBounds(300, 130, 150, 20);

        submit = new JButton();
        reset = new JButton();

        submit.setText("Submit");
        reset.setText("Reset");

        submit.setBounds(100, 200, 100, 20);
        reset.setBounds(200, 200, 100, 20);
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               Manufacturer = manfNameTXT.getText().toString();
               ModelNo = modelNoTXT.getText().toString();
               Year= yearTXT.getText().toString();
               Color= colorTXT.getText().toString();
               Cost= costTXT.getText().toString();
               System.out.println(Manufacturer + " " + ModelNo + " " + Year + " " + Color + " " + Cost);
               try {
                   resultSet = statement.executeQuery("insert into vehicle values(" + Manufacturer + "," + ModelNo + "," + Year + "," + Color + ","+Cost+")");
               } catch (SQLException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(Vehicles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }
           }
       });




    }



}
```

I dont know what is going wrong. please help

Comment: Make sure your jar file in classpath.

Comment: Indeed almost all the code you've posted is irrelevant - you could have demonstrated it with a `main` method which *just* called `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` - but you haven't shown us how you're running the code, which is the important part. In future, please try to post a *minimal* example.

Comment: @ravi  yes I have included the jar file in CLASSPATH in the Environment Variables

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using the following tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Comment: Please show your *exact* classpath, where the jar file is, etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar   Here is my jar file and I have set the path as CLASSPATH in the environment Variables

Comment: And how *exactly* are you running the program? Because if you were running it as per the tutorial, you wouldn't have "Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)". (Also, just because you're running a tutorial doesn't mean you can't get the program down to a minimal one which demonstrates the problem.) About 95% of the code you've posted is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using only the JDBC Connectivity not the full class of it

Comment: Well the bottom line is we *still* don't know exactly how you're running your code, and your question *still* contains about 120 lines too much code.

Comment: @JonSkeet see the logcat you dont have to read those 120 lines

Comment: I give up. The log doesn't tell me anything about how you're running the program - it just shows me the exception... and if we can ignore the rest of the code, then you should remove it from your question. Do you understand I've been trying to help you? How if you'd given us the information I asked for in the first comment, you'd probably have a working program by now? I'm afraid I don't have time to keep asking the same question (how are you running the program?) again and again, making no progress. This will be my last comment on this question - *please* provide requested info next time.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm just trying to make a JDBC Connection for the first time. I just want the data that  I input through the TextFields should be inserted in the database that I have made in MySQL. Thats it. When I am running the program it is not running and this exception comes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will give a go at it. The details of what Jon is driving at are very important, such as a container, or command line, I will post a demo in a minute or two

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Will try it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick Test Program

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class myTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/so_gibberish"; // **** MODIFY db name (my db_name is so_gibberish)
        String user = "username";   // **** MODIFY 
        String password = "my_password";    // **** MODIFY 

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            rs = st.executeQuery("select version()");

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println("------------------------------");
           }
            rs = st.executeQuery("select id,myCode from thingws");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+": "+rs.getString(2));
            }
            System.out.println("------------------------------");    

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(myTest.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(myTest.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I compile it in a folder (windows or linux)

```
C:\dev\java8\quick_java_mysql_test>javac myTest.java

C:\dev\java8\quick_java_mysql_test>
 (no errors)
```

I have a dep folder of dependencies under that folder

```
 Directory of C:\dev\java8\quick_java_mysql_test\dep

08/26/2015  10:29 AM    <DIR>          .
08/26/2015  10:29 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/17/2015  05:21 AM           968,670 mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
               1 File(s)        968,670 bytes
```

I run it with a command line classpath (cp) option flag to pick up class and the dep folder too:

```
C:\dev\java8\quick_java_mysql_test>java -cp ".;dep/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar" myTest

------------------------------
5.6.24-log
------------------------------
Oct 17, 2015 11:35:25 AM myTest main
SEVERE: Table 'so_gibberish.thingws' doesn't exist
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'so_gibberish.thingws' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
        at myTest.main(myTest.java:31)
```

### My classpath variable

not used. My strategy for this one is to have it project specific under the project folder. Others choose other strategies, and I often do with classpath variable.

You can also have a web container such as tomcat and web-inf, etc.

This is just a quick command line sanity check.

### Program output

The program above succeeds on the connect, dumps out the version of mysql, then simply fails on the use of a table that does not exist anymore

If I did not have a good classpath (cp) setup as described when running the program (what @JonSkeet was getting at), then in my case I would have encountered your error.

### Edit

Here it is with a classpath environment variable below:

```
classpath=.;c:\javadeps\*
```

### Output

Same as above, the driver is picked up in my common c:\javadeps